# How to change the animation for a 'neon-animatable' page in neon-animated-pages?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer's `neon-animated-pages` *entry* and *exit* animation attributes to slide my selected page from right to left. However when I tap my back button in the toolbar I really want to reverse the slide direction from left to right. How can change or reverse the animation in that case?

Polymer 1.0 code snippet:

```
<neon-animated-pages class="fit" entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" exit-animation="slide-left-animation" selected="{{selectedPage}}" attr-for-selected="id" on-iron-select="_pageChanged">
    <neon-animatable id="slide1">Page 1</neon-animatable>
    <neon-animatable id="slide2">Page 2</neon-animatable>
    <neon-animatable id="slide3">Page 3</neon-animatable>
</neon-animated-pages>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binding on the entry/exit animation properties like so:

```
<neon-animated-pages class="fit" entry-animation="[[entryAnimation]]" exit-animation="[[exitAnimation]]" selected="{{selectedPage}}" attr-for-selected="id" on-iron-select="_pageChanged">
```

Then update those properties to the desired animations as needed (i.e. when the back button is pressed, etc).